# Fake an ipv6 connection to a site

Tags: networking, internet, ipv6, telnet

I recently visited `telnet://towel.blinkenlights.nl` and it said that to unlock more artwork and colours, I need to visit it using ipv6. But I have an ipv4 connection and can't use ipv6.

So, I am looking for ways to fake an ipv6 connection to the site. How do I do it?

Comment: You might be able to setup some form of IPv6 tunnel. So your machine would be using IPv6 if your connection doesn't support it by default.

Comment: @Seth Thanks for the prompt response! Could you please elaborate the procedure of setting up an ipv6 tunnel?

Comment: No, I haven't done it because I never needed to. An alternative might be to use a proxy. But doing that using telnet might be hard.

Comment: You could find what you're looking for by googling ipv4 to ipv6. It'll give you vpn services. It is not possible to fake it otherwise because ipv6 is a network protocol, not a statistic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an IPv6 address, you need to contact your ISP and find out if they can give you a public IPv6 address. Depending on where you live this might be impossible until ISPs adopt IPv6 support.

[This website provides additional details and information regarding IPv6 procurement](http://test-ipv6.com/)